# Use of hypothesis to prove a tautology

Tags: propositional-logic

> Given $$ (¬(P ∧¬Q)⇒S)∧¬P ∧(R⇒¬S) ⇒ ¬R $$ prove that this is a tautology.

One way is to use a hypothesis taken from the proposition itself.

As an example:
If we want to prove this rule: $P ⇒ (P ∧ Q ≡ Q)$ , we can do as follows:

We prove the equation $P ∧ Q ≡ Q$ using the hypothesis $P$ as justification:

$$P ∧ Q$$
$$ ≡ \{Hypothesis: P, P ≡ T \} $$
$$T ∧ Q $$
$$ ≡ \{Unity \} $$
$$Q$$

How do I do the same thing, with the proposition i wrote at the beginning?

---

]Proof system example:

[[image]

It's in italian but it should be clear, those in brackets are, for example, the Commutative or Associative property.

Comment: Could you rephrase/clarify your question a little? It is unclear what you are asking.  Are you trying to avoid making standard boolean algebraic manipulations?

Comment: I have to prove it through a formal proof (a derivation). I cannot make, for example, P →  T, Q →  F, S →  T, R → T and then check the values according to the table.

Comment: You'll have to explain what kind of formal proof system you are supposed to use. There are several ones and we cannot guess which one is used in your class.

Comment: I don't understand. What is "the hypothesis of the proposition itself"? What does $P\Rightarrow (P\land Q\equiv Q)$ have to do with the thing you're trying to prove?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I put a picture, I hope that it makes that clear.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, that was just an example for how you prove something using the P as justification

Comment: We need a complete list of axioms. Otherwise we can't know what you're allowed to use.

Comment: Probably I cannot manage to explain myself, I only know the italian terminology and I can't find anything similar in english online. But thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

(¬(P∧¬Q)⇒S)∧¬P∧(R⇒¬S)⇒¬R

I've added in an extra parens for clarity:

((¬(P∧¬Q)⇒S)∧¬P∧(R⇒¬S))⇒¬R

First, replace x⇒y with ¬x∨y.  This is definitional.

¬ ((¬¬(P∧¬Q)∨ S)∧¬P∧(¬R∨¬S)) ∨ ¬R

Cancel out ¬¬

¬ (((P∧¬Q)∨ S)∧¬P∧(¬R∨¬S)) ∨ ¬R

Demorgan's in your first ¬

(¬((P∧¬Q)∨ S) ∨ ¬¬P ∨ ¬(¬R∨¬S)) ∨ ¬R

Cancel out ¬¬

(¬((P∧¬Q)∨ S) ∨ P ∨ ¬(¬R∨¬S)) ∨ ¬R

Demorgan's in your outer ¬s

((¬(P∧¬Q)∧ ¬S) ∨ P ∨ (¬¬R∧¬¬S)) ∨ ¬R

Cancel out ¬¬

((¬(P∧¬Q)∧ ¬S) ∨ P ∨ (R ∧ S)) ∨ ¬R

Demorgan's again:

(((¬P ∨ ¬¬Q) ∧ ¬S) ∨ P ∨ (R ∧ S)) ∨ ¬R

Cancel out ¬¬ one last time

(((¬P ∨ Q) ∧ ¬S) ∨ P ∨ (R ∧ S)) ∨ ¬R

Drop outer parens (using associativity)

((¬P ∨ Q) ∧ ¬S) ∨ P ∨ (R ∧ S) ∨ ¬R

Use the distributive property on the first term

((¬P∧ ¬S) ∨ (Q ∧ ¬S)) ∨ P ∨ (R ∧ S) ∨ ¬R

Drop parens (using associativity)

(¬P ∧ ¬S) ∨ (Q ∧ ¬S) ∨ P ∨ (R ∧ S) ∨ ¬R

At this point, we have a chain of or statements.  Use the distributive property on the last 2 terms:

(¬P ∧ ¬S) ∨ (Q ∧ ¬S) ∨ P ∨ ((R ∨ ¬R) ∧ (S ∨ ¬R))

(R ∨ ¬R) is always true, and T ∧ x ≡ x, thus:

(¬P ∧ ¬S) ∨ (Q ∧ ¬S) ∨ P ∨ S ∨ ¬R

Commutative property:

(¬P ∧ ¬S) ∨ P ∨ (Q ∧ ¬S) ∨ S ∨ ¬R

We will repeat the procedure with the distributive property on `(¬P ∧ ¬S) ∨ P` and on `(Q ∧ ¬S) ∨ S`:

((¬P  ∨ P) ∧ (¬S ∨ P)) ∨ ((Q ∨ S) ∧ (¬S ∨ S)) ∨ ¬R
(T ∧ (¬S ∨ P)) ∨ ((Q ∨ S) ∧ T) ∨ ¬R
¬S ∨ P ∨ Q ∨ S ∨ ¬R

Commutative property:

¬S ∨ S ∨ P ∨ Q ∨ ¬R

`¬S ∨ S` is T, and True or'd with anything becomes True by domination.

Comment: Thank you, that one possibility. The exercises specified to use another technique, but I'm not able to explain it here, so I will try to gather more information and then I'll do another question. But thanks, that's also been useful.